# How to copy record from one table to the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a insert select query in my stored procedure. In the query below, I inserted one record. What I want to do is to copy this record and insert to the same table but the salary will be negative. I am not sure what how to do it. Help will be appreciated

Here is part of my code

```
Insert into employee_name, age, Sum(salary)
Select employee_name, age, salary from employee
group by employee_name
```

Record

```
   employee_name  age    salary
   John           39    $30,000
```

What I want

```
employee_name   age    salary
John            39    $30,000
John            39    $-30,000
```

Comment: You want to insert a value into `Sum(salary)`?

Comment: @MitchWheat  know that I can just multiply - value. But the table is empty, there is no records in that table. Therefore, if I just use -salary, I will only get this record  John            39    $-30,000

Comment: please look here to improve question to avoid chit chat :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your INSERT syntax is completely wrong. You could have easily looked it up in the docs: `INSERT INTO table (columns) SELECT ...`.

Then you say you want to copy a record but make the salary negative. What does that have to do with row aggregation (`SUM` and `GROUP BY`)?

It seems you simply want:

```
insert into employee (employee_name, age, salary)
select employee_name, age, -salary from employee;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basic SQL syntax for `insert` statement.

```
Insert into employee (employee_name, age, salary) 
Select employee_name, age, -Sum(salary) from employee
group by employee_name, age
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table employee
(
emp_id int,
employee_name varchar(50),
salary numeric,
Age int)
```

### Sol:

```
Insert into employee 
Select emp_id,employee_name, Sum(salary)*-1,age from employee
group by emp_id,employee_name, age
```

### Result:

```
emp_id  employee_name   salary  age
 101       Rajesh        3900   32
 101       Rajesh       -3900   32
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sum` it in the select statement then multiply to -1

```
Insert into employee
Select employee_name, age, Sum(salary) * -1 from employee
group by employee_name, age
```

Assuming that `employee` table has 3 columns `employee_name`, `age`, `salary`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I missed something. Fixed

Answer (score -3):

```
Insert into Employee (employee_name, age, salary)
Select employee_name, age, Sum(salary) from employee
group by employee_name, age

Insert into Employee (employee_name, age, salary)
Select employee_name, age, -Sum(salary)from employee
group by employee_name, age
```

This will do i haven't tested the code

Comment: have you ever seen t-sql syntax? -1

Comment: It's the part of the code, i just expanded it, doesn't matter T-sql or Not

Comment: your syntax doesn't match any SQL version. Do not copy / paste from OP.

Comment: @DragonBorn Please test my code, i just want to know if it works

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Thanks man i didn't read the GroupBy thing carefully... Thanks

Comment: No i just focused on 'how to get the negative' (i have up voted yours)

Comment: your insert statement is still all wrong. And there are two correct answers already.

Comment: You are missing the table name!

Comment: That's all? What about group by?

Comment: This is all silly things, happens when you don't test the code, Anyway Thanks and removing it, who would have thought anyone could miss the table name and used the group by in the insert statement,